# PHP removing a character in a string

Tags: php, string

My php is weak and I'm trying to change this string:

```
http://www.example.com/backend.php?/c=crud&m=index&t=care
                                   ^
```

to be:

```
http://www.example.com/backend.php?c=crud&m=index&t=care
                                  ^
```

removing the `/` after the `backend.php?`. Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should actually mark CMS' answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I think that it's better to use simply [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace), like the manual says:

> If you don't need fancy replacing
>   rules (like regular expressions), you
>   should always use this function
>   instead of ereg_replace()  or
>   preg_replace().

```
<?
$badUrl = "http://www.site.com/backend.php?/c=crud&m=index&t=care";
$goodUrl = str_replace('?/', '?', $badUrl);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\?\//', '?', $str);
```

Edit: See CMS' answer. It's late, I should know better.

Comment: str_replace is blindingly faster than a regex.

Comment: @Pestilence, that's why I recommended CMS' answer.

Answer (score 0):

While a regexp would suit here just fine, I'll present you with an alternative method. It *might* be a tad faster than the equivalent regexp, but life's all about choices (...or something).

```
$length = strlen($urlString);
for ($i=0; $i<$length; i++) {
  if ($urlString[$i] === '?') {
    $urlString[$i+1] = '';
    break;
  }
}
```

Weird, I know.

Comment: Er, what if $urlString[$i+1] isn't /?

Comment: eyelidlessness: the problem didn't present that case, so neither did my solution take it into account.

MDCore: please elaborate, why so?

Comment: I've run into a problem where it's useful.  If your string is on the order of megs in size (it can happen), running preg_replace or str_replace will risk hitting your php.ini's memory_limit. The pcre_replace code in php always mallocs 2x your string size before doing anything, so it can be an issue.

Comment: Going from my previous comment, if your string is really huge, you can do some strpos tricks to find the right pieces, preg_match them, and then use the above bracket notation to eliminate the characters you don't want.  Use with care, since it's not fast, but it will save memory.

Comment: This solution looks smart, but if I try it, it gives me an error:
 "Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset". What could the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
$splitPos = strpos($url, "?/");
if ($splitPos !== false) {
    $url = substr($url, 0, $splitPos) . "?" . substr($url, $splitPos + 2);
}
```