# Remove forward slash using php

Tags: php

I want to remove forward slash from below mentioned string using php

**Output**

```
$userheightfeet1 = $_POST["userheightfeet"];

5\'10
```

**Expected O/P**

```
  5'10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP removing a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264480/php-removing-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$userheightfeet1 = $_POST["userheightfeet"];

echo stripslashes($userheightfeet1);
```

Also you may use

```
$userheightfeet1 = $_POST["userheightfeet"];

echo str_replace('\','', $userheightfeet1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = "5\'10";

// 5'10
echo stripslashes($str);
?
```

Hope this helps!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used give code it will help you :-

```
 $str="5\'10";
 $str=stripslashes($str);
 echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function

```
    str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Replace what ever character you want to replace with "".